Why is the FID score of my StyleGAN model increasing as training progresses
I am training a StyleGAN model and I output the FID score every 10k iterations, here are the scores for introducing and stabilising phase of layer 3 (16x16) images.
Layer 3, Iteration 10000: 15.854619026184082
Layer 3, Iteration 20000: 10.223531723022461
Layer 3, Iteration 30000: 8.628936767578125
Layer 3, Iteration 40000: 7.515135765075684
Layer 3, Iteration 50000: 6.685100078582764
Layer 3, Iteration 60000: 6.110905647277832
Layer 3, Iteration 70000: 5.465500354766846
Layer 3, Iteration 80000: 5.1967244148254395
Layer 3, Iteration 90000: 4.944635391235352
Layer 3, Iteration 100000: 4.790095806121826
Layer 3, Iteration 110000: 4.8084282875061035
Layer 3, Iteration 120000: 4.636320114135742
Layer 3, Iteration 130000: 4.500547409057617
Layer 3, Iteration 140000: 4.467888832092285
Layer 3, Iteration 150000: 4.6545209884643555
Layer 3, Iteration 160000: 4.638757228851318
Layer 3, Iteration 170000: 4.777474880218506
Layer 3, Iteration 180000: 4.886040210723877
Layer 3, Iteration 190000: 4.659257411956787
Layer 3, Iteration final intro: 4.766842842102051
Layer 3, Iteration 0: 4.900529384613037
Layer 3, Iteration 10000: 4.680016994476318
Layer 3, Iteration 20000: 4.9469733238220215
Layer 3, Iteration 30000: 4.806821823120117
Layer 3, Iteration 40000: 4.856716156005859
Layer 3, Iteration 50000: 4.822808742523193
Layer 3, Iteration 60000: 4.774735927581787
Layer 3, Iteration 70000: 4.980378150939941
Layer 3, Iteration 80000: 5.036930084228516
Layer 3, Iteration 90000: 4.947129249572754
Layer 3, Iteration 100000: 4.921542644500732
Layer 3, Iteration 110000: 5.253421783447266
Layer 3, Iteration 120000: 5.036475658416748
Layer 3, Iteration 130000: 5.236703395843506
Layer 3, Iteration 140000: 5.2556891441345215
Layer 3, Iteration 150000: 5.264438152313232

We see that the scores are increasing in the stabilising phase, has anybody any idea why?
My network does not employ style mixing or the truncation trick.
